# Limit the doctrine pagination total records in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, pagination

I have a table with hundreds of thousand registers. I´m doing a pagination page with search capabilities using Zend Framework 3 and Doctrine 2. My problem is that I would like to limit the total number of registers to 500 independent of the search parameters and the pagination.

On the Controller:

```
// This will return the result of DQL
$registros = $this->regService->getRegisters($searchParameters);

$adapter = new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($registros, false));
$paginator = new Paginator($adapter);
$paginator->setDefaultItemCountPerPage(20);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

return new ViewModel([   
    'registros' => $paginator
]);
```

So, the problem is that if I do a search with parameters thar get 2 thousand registers, the pagination will return all these registers and what I want to do is limit in 500 register

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

From the code I'm not quite sure where your problem is; the implementation of the `getRegisters($param)` is missing.

However, to implement pagination you're on the right path.

Try the following:

```
$page = $this->params()->fromQuery('page', 1);
$itemsPerPage = $this->params()->fromQuery('itemsPerPage', null);

// I'm assuming your `getRegisters($param)` function returns QueryBuilder object
/** @var QueryBuilder $qb */
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

// This query gets everything from Entity "Entity"
$qb->select('shortEntityName')
    ->from(\Namespace\To\Entity::class, 'shortEntityName');

// Create a Paginator, pass the QueryBuilder as parameter
$paginator = new Paginator(new OrmAdapter(new OrmPaginator($qb)));

// Set the current page (should be received from URL GET request)
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

// Set the max items per page, defaulting to max of 500
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage($itemsPerPage ?: 500);

return [
    'paginator' => $paginator,
];
```

---

Next to this you should also have a 'pagination' partial template somewhere you use for the pagination navigation, to use in the view. This template should accommodate the way you add the different GET parameters, e.g. `&page=2` for the second page or `&itemsPerPage=100` to show 100 items on a page instead of 500.

---

Based on comment, slightly revised last functions on the `$paginator`.

```
// If using code above, you can discard getting "itemsPerPage" from URL, no longer required

// Set the current page (should be received from URL GET request)
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber(($page <= 10) ? $page : 10); // max allowed = 10

// Set the max items per page, defaulting to max of 500
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(50); // always 50 per page
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. The pagination is working well. The problem is that if the query retuns more than 500 registers, I would like to ignore they. So if retuns 600 records I should have only 10 pages with 50 records each and the other 100 should be discarded.

Comment: I've added a bit below the answer that should have this for you. You'll need to devise a way to limit the pagination for this page on the client-side yourself though (max 10 pages, though the back-end will correct it).